# Change DNS Handling From Zerigo Without Downtime

Tags: domain-name-system, heroku, zerigo

Zerigo have just removed their free plan. As a result I need to switch out my DNS handling. The problem is that the site is live, so I need to minimize any downtime.

Currently Zerigo handles both the naked domain and the `www` subdomain. So far as I can see I need to do the following:

1. Switch nameservers back to my domain registra's
2. Add a CNAME for `www`, pointing to `example.herokuapp.com`
3. Add an A record, pointing to wwwizer's IP address (`174.129.25.170`), with Wwwizer handling redirection of the naked domain.

But how can I do this without downtime?

Comment: Their removing of their free DNS hosting plan doesn't necessarily qualify as a bait and switch. Did they promise you one thing and then deliver another or is it simply a matter of their changing to a pricing/service model that no longer includes a free plan? Your statement may very well be libelous and you'd better make darn sure you're right before you go around writing such things. You may be upset about losing your free plan but that doesn't give you the right to accuse them of criminal activity unless you can prove it.

Comment: A big +1 for @joeqwerty. "We no longer have a free plan" isn't bait-and-switch.

Comment: @joeqwerty You are right. My use understanding of bate-and-switch was incorrect. I thought it referred to a common retail tactic rather than an explicitly criminal activity. However I do believe that offering a free tier in something so critical to a website, then removing it with 4 weeks notice is a pretty harsh move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up DNS elsewhere *then* change the nameservers via your registrars to those new servers.

There is no technical requirement requiring a domain to 'point at' a name server to set up that zone.  Set everything up, then cut over.

Your DNS provider may not allow you to 'add' a domain without changing the nameservers first (or at the same time) but that's an artificial limitation they are placing on it.  You either live with it, or you find another provider.